# Передача значения input в переменную

Tags: php, html

Имеется форма с передачей значений на сервер robokassa

```
<form method="post" action "url robokassa"
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Логин" name="login" >  
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ID группы" name="group_id" >  
<button type="submit">Кнопка</button>
$login = $_POST['login'];
$gid = $_POST['group_id'];
```

Необходимо, чтобы после нажатия на кнопку сразу же записывались значения input'ов в переменные $login и $gid, а после этого передавались значения на сервер rk
Но используя данные код значения передаются пустые

Вот js отправки пост запроса, имеется форма с неск. input и код js

```
print "<script language=JavaScript".  
"src='https://auth.robokassa.ru/Merchant/PaymentForm/FormMS.js?".  
"MrchLogin=$mrh_login&OutSum=$out_summ&InvId=$inv_id".  "&shp_email=$shp_email&shp_gid=$shp_gid&shp_login=$shp_login&shp_server=$shp_server&shp_srok=$shp_srok".  
"&Desc=$inv_desc&SignatureValue=$crc".  
"&Culture=$culture&Encoding=$encoding'></script>";
```

Значения в переменные $shp_ мне надо добавить до начала работы скрипта

Comment: Обновил вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Не вариант сразу пост запросы передавать? Зачем их записывать в переменные и отсылать куда-то, если  form action сам позаботится об этом

Answer (score 0):

Так пост после сабмита приходит, почитай внимательно основы.

Comment: Так а как тогда записать значения в переменные?

Comment: AJAX, если это действительно нужно, или же поменять логику-> передавать на другой файл и там писать в переменные.

Comment: Пробую передать переменные в другой файл, который находится уже на моем сервере, итог тот же, значения пост запроса - пустые.

Comment: наверняка тебе и правда надо почитать основы основ.
Работа с формами происходит данным образом:

<form method="post" action "url robokassa"
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Логин" name="login" >  
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ID группы" name="group_id" >  
<button  name="go" type="submit">Кнопка</button>
</form> <!-- Не забудь ее закрыть -->
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['go'])){
      $login = $_POST['login'];
      $gid = $_POST['group_id'];
      echo $login . " -- ".$gid; 
  }
?>

Comment: На деле у меня вместо кнопки идет js, чтобы его передать, нужны записанные значения в переменные.

Comment: Так пиши js:
   
    <script>      
      $("button").unbind("click").on("click",function(e){   
           var name = $("[name='login']").val();      
           var gid = $("name='group_id'").val();      
           alert(name+" ---- "+gid);    
           return false;    
      });   
    </script> 
         
А дальше уже ajax на файл, если это надо.

Comment: Не очень лажу с js.    
Ваш скрипт выполнит мою задачу?    
Т.е. имеется форма с неск. input и код js: 
 
    print "<script language=JavaScript".  
    "src='https://auth.robokassa.ru/Merchant/PaymentForm/FormMS.js?".  
    "MrchLogin=$mrh_login&OutSum=$out_summ&InvId=$inv_id".  "&shp_email=$shp_email&shp_gid=$shp_gid&shp_login=$shp_login&shp_server=$shp_server&shp_srok=$shp_srok".  
    "&Desc=$inv_desc&SignatureValue=$crc".  
    "&Culture=$culture&Encoding=$encoding'></script>";  

Значения в переменные `$shp_` мне надо добавить до начала работы скрипта.

Comment: Бред... А в чем тогда вопрос? Ни с php, ни с js не лажу... Тогда надо бы основы почитать, что такое форма и как она предается.

Answer (score 0):

А зачем вам записывать их в переменные? Они же передадутся постом, или вы хотите сказать, что пост идет пустым?

Comment: Да, пост запрос идет пустой.

Comment: Отправьте эту форму на адрес http://devpl.net/test.php и напишите, что вам выдало.

Comment: Странно, но на этот адрес значения передаются.
____

Вот так принимаю значения во втором файле:

    $shp_email = $_POST['login'];
    $shp_gid = $_POST['group_id'];

Comment: Если вы выложили тот код, что действительно у вас, то у вас не закрыта форма, может, из-за этого.

Comment: Вот так принимаю значения во втором файле $shp_email = $_POST['login']; $shp_gid = $_POST['group_id'];  - попробуйте написать без одинарных кавычек или просто напишите print_r($_POST)

Comment: мы немного отошли от вопроса, мне необходимо записать значения в переменную, тк post запрос идет не по нажатию на кнопку, а при помощи js

Comment: то есть, они передаются при помощи $.post()?